# jQuery addClass only add the class for the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class to all elements which have a defined class name.

There is my code:

```
$(settings.slidesPlaceholder + ' ' + settings.slideIdentifier)
        .removeClass('active-slide')
        .addClass('inactive-slide');
```

But the issue is that the class is added only for the first element, but is removed from all elements.

Comment: Your code should work. However Can you reproduce the issue in  a snippet?

Comment: Is the class selector coming from your settings as well? As in is `settings.slidesPlaceHolder` set as `.aDefaultSlider`?

Comment: please provide more information

Answer (score -1):

Please just make sure, you are not using `id` attribute for changing `class`.

**For example:**

```
$("#divid").removeClass('a').addClass('b');
$(body).removeClass('a').addClass('b');
```

The above will gonna add Class only to one element.

```
$(".cldiv").removeClass('a').addClass('b');
```

The above will update all elements with class `cldiv`.

So just `console.log` your `settings.slidesPlaceholder+''+settings.slideIdentifier`

and see whether its a `class`, `id` or `element`.